# Differences between iOS 7 API and iOS 6 API

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

I'm having few iPhone and iPad apps which are developed by using iOS 6 SDK. I want to convert them in to iOS 7. When I'm trying to do this, there were so many issues occurred. So, is there any place to see a list of changes in iOS 7 with compare to iOS 6 and any guidens for the conversion of apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS70APIDiffs/index.html) is the ultimate answer what I was looking for. I hope this will be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 4):

You should see the [What's New in iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW1) and the [WWDC 2013 videos](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/). Apple has a ton of resources to this end out on https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Answer (score 2):

Apple have provide many document on this topic :

[Whats new in iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW1)

[Submit your iOS 7 apps today.](https://developer.apple.com/ios7/)

[iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174)

[Designing for iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556)

[WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/)

This may also become new source but we have to wait for this : [iOS 7 Tech Talk](https://developer.apple.com/tech-talks/)

You will find other non - apple document also. search internet and ask question when you stuck in try. don't ask before you try.